# Erased project from Project Explorer and cannot re-import it

Tags: android, eclipse

I erased a project from the Project Explorer, because I didn't think I had everything in the Workspace folder that it needed.  I was getting error messages.  When I got the complete project into the workspace folder and tried to re-import it I get this message: "Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace."

The three folders of the project show up in the window, but are greyed out and cannot be selected.

Thanks to Arun and Francis below.... but new problem

OK. Great! Got passed that one deleting from hard disk and creating a new workspace folder. But now when I try to run it as an Android Application I get the message, "No compatible targets were found. Do you wish to add new Android Virtual device? And in the Console: "Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Google APIs'." I'm really new to this so thanks for whatever patience you have to answer newbie questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try back up your project folder and delete the project completely from project explorer and from the hard disk. Make your backed up project folder into a zip file and try re-import it and recreate a separate project copy in your workspace. If this doesn't work, try switching workspace...... :)

Comment: OK.  Great!  Got passed that one deleting from hard disk and creating a new workspace folder.  But now when I try to run it as an Android Application I get the message, "No compatible targets were found.  Do you wish to add new Android Virtual device?  And in the Console: "Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Google APIs'."  I'm really new to this so thanks for whatever patience you have to answer newbie questions.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like the project is still there in the workspace, so try deleting it again. When you delete it, make sure you select the option "Delete files on the disk", this will actually remove the underlying file in addition to just removing the project definition from the workspace.

If you still have trouble (that is, the project is still there), delete the files from the workspace associated with the project by hand (in the operating system). And then Refresh the project and try deleting it from the workspace again (don't select the option to delete files on disk). It should be gone then.

Once the project is gone from the workspace and the underlying files are gone, try your import again.

Comment: Oops!  I should have refreshed this screen before I answered the comment from Arun. - " 
OK. Great! Got passed that one deleting from hard disk and creating a new workspace folder. But now when I try to run it as an Android Application I get the message, "No compatible targets were found. Do you wish to add new Android Virtual device? And in the Console: "Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Google APIs'." I'm really new to this so thanks for whatever patience you have to answer newbie questions."

Comment: @user679336 the next year your getting about setting up your AVD is basically saying you need to setup your android emulator.  Check out Step 4 from this link it should help you out: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Comment: I've been meaning to ask about this.  When I open the Window menu, there is no single menu item called "Android SDK and AVD Manager".  They are 2 separate menu items.  Yet in all the books and on forums on the internet it's referred to one menu item, "Android SDK and AVD Manager".  What am I missing here?

Comment: @user679336 : you may not have properly installed ADT plugin in eclipse 'assuming that you are using eclispe IDE' :) only if you install eclipse ADT plugin it will show those options :) And I have another suggestion for you try completing your profile with your name and other stuffs :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use working sets, make sure they are all deselected. Only the projects from the current working set will display in Project Explorer. By having no working sets selected you can see all the conflicting projects in Project Explorer and delete them by hand. Then re-import.